# Time Complexity of 3 nested for loops

Tags: time, complexity-theory

Although, I found pretty good replies to the same question! However, I want time complexity equation of the following piece of code

```
sum = 0;                                            c1=11
for (i=0; i<N; i++)                                 c2=6
    for (j=0; j<N; j++)                             c2=6
        for (j=0; j<N; j++)                         c2=7
    sum += arr[i][j]                                c3=2
```

While each statement has a cost associated with it, I require complete time complexity equation and its answer.

Regards

Comment: Well technically this is constant time. There is no variable input. It will always take 125 steps. Or depending on the language this might not even compile because you have two loops that use j

Comment: Let's consider third loop has 'k' instead of 'j', then what?

Comment: Doesn't matter, you always looping exactly 5 times each. No matter what input you pass into this program (assuming there is one), it will always take 125 steps which is O(1), the number of iterations would need to depend on a variable value to be anything else

Comment: Ok agreed. But what shall be the equation involving cost associations c1, c2, c3 in terms of N² or N³?

Comment: That is what I have been trying to tell you. There it NO N here. All of these loops are N^0 = 1 please read about constant time here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Constant_time For this algorithm to be N^2 or N^3 it would have to be ```(i=0; i< n; i++)``` see how there is a variable n here. that is where the N in the big-o comes from

Comment: Sir, thanks for your patient response. But, if you don't mind, if we replace 5 by N, then will it be following some time complexity? And what shall be the equation?

Comment: And I've changed the question now!

Comment: No problem my friend. We are here to help. The comments got too long. I am going to write a detailed answer in a moment

Answer (score 1):

The comments section got quite long so I am going to write up an answer summarizing everything.

**Measuring Time Complexity**

In Computer Science, we measure time complexity by the number of steps/iterations your algorithm takes to evaluate.

So if you have a simple array of length `n` and you go through this array only once, say to print all the elements, we say that this algorithm is `O(n)` because the time is takes to run will grow proportionally to the size of the array you have, thus `n`

You can think of Big-O `O(..)` as a higher order function that compares other functions. if we say `f(x) = O(n)` it means that you function grows **at most** as fast as `y=n` thus linearly. This means that if you were to plot these functions on a graph, there would be a point c `x = c` after which the graph of `n` will always be on top of f(x) for any given x > c. Big-O signifies upper bound of a function in terms of another function.

So let's look at your original question and what it means to be constant time. Say we have this function

```
def printFirst5(arr: Array[Int]) = {

     for(i =0 ;i < 5; i++){
         println(arr[i])
     }
 }
```

This is what we call a constant time algorithm. Can you see why? Because no matter what array you pass into this (as long as it has at least 5 elements), it will only go through the first 5 elements. You can pass it an array of length `100000000000` you can pass it an array of length `10` it doesn't matter. In each case it will only look at the first 5 elements. Meaning this function `printFirst5` will never go above the line `y=5` in terms of time complexity. These kind of functions are denoted `O(1)` for constant time.

Now, finally, let's look at you edited version. (I am not sure what you are trying to do in your example because it is syntactically wrong, so I will write my own example)

```
    def groupAllBy3(array: Array[Int]) = {
       for(i=0; i < array.length; i++){
          for(j=0; j < array.length; j++){
            for(k=0; k< array.length; k++{
              println(s"$array[i], $array[j], $array[k]")
           }
         } 
       }
    }
```

This functions time complexity is O(N<sup>3</sup>). Why? Let's take a look.

The innermost loop will go through N elements for every `j`
How many `j`s are there? Well there will be N `j`s for every `i`.
How many `i`s are there? `N` many.

So in total we get `numberof-i * numberof-j * numberof-k = N * N * N = O(N^3)`

Just to make sure you understand this correctly, let's take a look at another example. What would happen if these loops weren't nested? If we had:

```
    def printAllx3(array: Array[Int]) = {
       for(i=0; i < array.length; i++){
           println(s"array[i]")
       }

       for(j=0; j < array.length; j++){
           println(s"array[j]") 
       } 

       for(k=0; k< array.length; k++{
              println(s"array[k]")
        }
    }
```

What is the case here?

The first loop goes through N elements, the second loop goes through N elements, the third loop goes through N elements. But they don't depend on each other in terms of iterations so we get `N + N + N = 3N = O(N)`

Do you see the difference?

With all due respect, I believe you are missing some of the fundamentals of what time complexity is & how we measure it. There is only so much I can explain here, I highly recommend you do some reading on the subject and ask any further questions you don't understand.

Hope this helps